# Is it possible to track memory usage in a C# application without using a profiler?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management

I'd like to write a simple application which keeps track of its current memory usage, number of created objects etc. In C++ I'd normally override the new operator, but for obvious reasons I can't do this in C#. Is there any way to do this without using a profiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to start with the Garbage Collector.  MSDN has some members listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc_members.aspx) that can show you how to do a few things, like get the total amount of memory it thinks is allocated, how many times the GC has collected.  Anything more advanced than that, like getting a count of objects of your loaded assembly and you'll have to probably use a profiler or write something yourself.

Answer (score 1):

.NET Memory performance counters will  give you aggregate information, but does not include object counters. For that you will need a profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Using WMI try :

To get process usage (W2K3/2K8) :

```
"SELECT IDProcess, PercentPrivilegedTime, PercentProcessorTime, PercentUserTime FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process where Name='process_name.exe'"
```

To identify your site use this :

```
"SELECT ProcessId, CommandLine, WorkingSetSize, ThreadCount, PrivatePageCount, PageFileUsage, PageFaults, HandleCount, CreationDate, Caption FROM Win32_Process where Caption='process_name.exe'"
```

Use this tool for [WQL teste](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/NitoWMI)

Or use PerfMon tool.

For more information about counters see [Windows System Resource Manager Accounting](http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/2/5/d2524d17-b893-46f9-bebe-b1f7b927e144/Windows%20System%20Resource%20Manager%20Accounting.doc), at the end of doc.

Good luck.